# Magic Wanding One Particular Color At Once--Is That Possible?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

For years, I've been working on a worldbuilding/alternate history project but am currently struggling because I need a global map to get the job really done.  Sure, on Photoshop, I can use Paint Brush to create mountains, but a big, squiggly line won't give an accurate portrayal of a mountain range's shape or size, which is why, using municipal base maps, I have found that using Paint Bucket is more desirable than Paint Brush.

A more reliable tool that I've often used is Magic Wand, and that's where we first get to the question.  Presented here is an image of one of South America's nations under a geological map:

[image]

In this scenario, I have decided to use Magic Wand to select any of the colors presented in the legend and then Command-J that color, turning it transparent.  To save time, I have thought about using Magic Wand to select all of that one same color at once and Commanding-J from there.  Is this sort of thing possible?  If the first answer is yes, then what steps would I take to go there?

Comment: Just out of curiosty why dont you sue something that is more suitable for your task?

Comment: Maps like these shouldn’t be made in Photoshop to begin with. They’re much better suited for vector graphics and thus for vector-based apps like Illustrator.

Comment: @joojaa  I'm afraid I don't follow you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can switch off the "contiguous" option in the tool options for that. Then it will select all areas of colour which are the same.

For example:

[image]

Comment: See also: Select > Colour Range. Might be useful if you need to tweak the tolerance as you go.

Comment: I'd been doing as you suggested, but it turns out that the border lines are just too thin, even at a tolerance of 5.

Answer (score 0):

another way to select all of the pixels in an image with the same color is to use the 'color range...' dialog under the 'Select' menu

from the dialog, change the fuzziness to 0 (to select only that specific color) and the radio button to image. use the eye dropper to select a pixel of the color in question on the image and the press 'OK' for all of the same color pixels on the image to become selected.